# Merging from one Git branch to another after getting the error "multiple merge bases found"

Tags: git, egit

I have a Git repository with three branches, master, 2.x and 3.x.  2.x and 3.x originated from master.  Weekly releases are made to production from the master branch.  2.x and 3.x contain work that will be released a little far off in the future.  Immediately after making a production release from the master branch we merge from the master branch to both 2.x and 3.x so that the latest production code gets into 2.x and 3.x as well.  In addition, frequently, we merge from 2.x to 3.x as well as the features being developed on 3.x eventually need to be integrated with the features being developed on 2.x.

Last week, after we merged from master to 2.x and 3.x, we discovered that no one had made any changes to 3.x between the just concluded merge from master and the previous merge from master.  Now, when we try to merge from 2.x to 3.x, the merge operation fails with the error "multiple merge bases found".

Is it possible to merge from 2.x to 3.x, now that we are in this situation?  We use EGit with Eclipse Indigo as the Git client.

Comment: jgit and gerrit have this problem, I don't think the real one does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @jthill.  I merged using a Linux command line client and the merge succeeded.